# Raspberrypi でopencv エラー

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

まったくの初心者です。

Raspberry3 model B+ , Raspbian , Thonny(Simple Mode)を使っています。

LXTerminal でOpencv(2.4.9.1)をｲﾝｽﾄｰﾙしましたがpython2でインストールされてました。
Python3 でOpencvを扱うにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？

バージョンはPython2.7.13, Python3.5.3でした。

インストールしたときのコマンド
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get python-opencv
sudo apt-get libopencv-dev

Python3でimport cv2 としたらNo module named 'cv2'
Python2でimport cv2 としたらそのまま問題なくできました。

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry PiのPythonのデフォルトは2.x系なので、apt-getでpython系のものをインストールすると、デフォルトである2.x系に合わせたものがインストールされます。Python3もデフォルトで入っていたか、あるいはapt-getで入れたものと推察します。Pythonのパッケージコントローラであるpipのうち、python3用のものをいれて対応するのが手っ取り早いかと思います。

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
$ sudo pip3 install opencv-python
```